# polynomials and symmetric functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a polynomial function $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dotsc, x_k],$ such that whenever $r_1, \dotsc, r_k$ are roots of a monic polynomial of degree $k$ with integer coefficients, we have $f(r_1, \dotsc, r_k) \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Is it true that $f$ is a symmetric function of its arguments?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is symmetric in its arguments whenever the Galois group of $r_1, \dots r_k$ is the full symmetric group $S_k$. The set of tuples of algebraic integers with this property is almost certainly Zariski dense in $\mathbb{A}^n$ (although I can't prove it off the top of my head), and so if two polynomials (namely $f$ and one of its permutations) are equal on this set of tuples then they're identical.

Comment: This is where I got stuck too :)

Comment: @Igor: perhaps it follows from Hilbert irreducibility? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_irreducibility_theorem)

Comment: Yes, that's possible, although not quite in the wikipedia form, since the field here is $\overline{\mathbb{Q}},$ not $\mathbb{Q},$ but maybe that is Hilbertian, as well...

Comment: Yes, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is Hilbertian: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Haran's_diamond_theorem, so maybe the strong version of Hilbert irreducibility (that the irreducible specializations are Z-dense) applied to a resolvent polynomial does the trick...